# A Simple Expectation Calculation For a Fractional i.i.d. Random Variables

Tags: probability, expectation

Suppose $X,Y$ are i.i.d. having density $f$ and $X,Y>-1$, I would like to calculate
$$
E\left[ \frac{XY-1}{2+X+Y}\right].
$$

I was confusing about the following thinking: Because of i.i.d., am I allowed to write
$$
E\left[ \frac{XY-1}{2+X+Y}\right] = ? =E\left[ \frac{X^2-1}{2+2X}\right]
$$ I think not but not very clear about this. Any suggestion/comment is appreciated.

Comment: Of course you are not… otherwise for i.i.d. r.v. it always hold that $$E\left[(X-Y)^2\right] = E\left[(X-X)^2\right] = 0$$ and so $$X = Y$$ what's nonsense obviously 

You note that they have a "distribution $f$" but actually with $f$ the density is denoted… do $X$ & $Y$ have a density?

Comment: Definetely not. That needs no argumentation but only a counterexample.

Comment: @Gono, Thanks for reply! For the $f$, I mean density, sorry for adding extra layer of confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the fact that $E(g(x,y))=\int_{-1}^{\infty}\int_{-1}^{\infty} \frac{xy-1}{2+x+y}f_{X,Y}(x,y) dy dx$ Now, use the fact that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x).f_Y(y)$